# Why does cookies stored on Chrome browser with Node.js automatically deletes after page reloads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I created a blog site with React which I deployed on vercel and Node which I deployed on render.

The blog site was created so users can read and react to my blogs. To cut the story short, I tried remembering users after login with cookie which worked out but not perfectly well as I expected.

When a user logs in, I send a cookie which will be stored in the browser but after this cookie is stored, it will be deleted after the page reloads or closes even though the expiration is set to 90 days.

Here is the code from the server:

`

```
res.cookie('CLIENT_JWT', token, {

            maxAge: maxAge * 1000,

            httpOnly: true,

            secure: true,

            sameSite: 'None',

            domain: 'supreme-news-server.onrender.com', 

            path: '/'

            

        });`
```

And here is the code from the client:
`

```
fetch('https://supreme-news-server.onrender.com/client/login', {

        method: 'POST',

        credentials: 'include',

        body: JSON.stringify({

            email,pwd

        }),

        headers: {

            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

        }

    })

    .then((data) => {

        resolve(data.json())

    })

    .catch(err => {

        reject(err)

    })`
```

After a deep research on why this happens, I got a hint about cookies from different domain which is displayed on the cookies tab in the network tools.

So the cookies received was highlighted with yellow colour with a warning. I have tried everything I could. I have changed sameSite to all options available yet still get same result.

I have tried changing secure to false but I get a warning about that so I set it back to true.

Answer (score 0):

You have set maxAge property to maxAge * 1000;
and i can not see variable maxAge anywhere in your code. so define maxAge in seconds.

example:

```
maxAge: 24*60*60, (for one day)
```

Comment: Max age is set to 90 days

Comment: try omitting the domain and path property. if not specified, browser automatically sets domain property to the host name. and put maxage directly in numbers rather than using variable.